# Assistance with positioning pictures and text please

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(58, 58, 58);
    color: black;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

header {
    background-color: blue;
    padding: 30px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    background-image: url("../bilder/hjem.jpeg");
    background-position: center;
}

.Bilder {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}

section {
    background-color: white;
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
}

/*  .Spill - Bildene på hjemmesiden  */
.spill {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    padding: 30px 50px;
    display: flex;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    flex-direction: row;
}

.spill img {
    margin-left: 100px;
}

#SanderBilde {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    left: 200px;
}

#FotografBilde {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 230px;
    width: 230px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    color: black;
    left: 260px;
}

#DestinyBilde {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    width: 230px;
    height: 230px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 20px;
    color: black;
    position: relative;
    left: 300px;
}

/* Tekst under bildene */

.Undertekst {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    color: black;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.Undertekst div {
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: large;
    background-color: white;
    text-decoration: solid;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 10px 20px;
}

#div1 {
    position: relative;
    left: 95px;
}

#div2 {
    position: relative;
    right: 14px;
}

#div3 {
    position: relative;
    right: 11%;
}


/*  Hjemmeside Informasjon  */

.Informasjon {
    background-color: white;
}

#Informasjon {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 1000px;
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    right: 480px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

/*  Navbar  */

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}

h1 {
    border: 3px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 60px 60px 60px 60px;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 41%;
}

li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 20px 15px;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 35px;
}

/*  Innhold på nettsiden  */ 

div {
    width: 100px;
    margin: auto;
}

footer{
    background-color: black;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: medium;
    font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;

}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    padding: 35px 15px;
}

.active {
    background-color: aquamarine;
}

a:hover{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:focus{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hjem</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Hjem</a></li>
                <li><a href="./Sider/side4.html">Spill</a></li>
                <li><a href="./Sider/side2.html">Om meg</a></li>
                <li><a href="./Sider/side3.html">Portfolio</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
        <h1>Hjem</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="Bilder">
      <img id="SanderBilde" src="./bilder/64514143_459156374657957_2516012904516419584_n.jpeg" alt="Bilde av Sander">
      <img id="FotografBilde" src="./bilder/foto2.jpeg" alt="Bilde av en fotograf">
      <img id="DestinyBilde" src="./bilder/destinyside2.png" alt="Bilde av Destiny 2">
    </section>

    <section class="Undertekst">
        <div id="div1">
           <p><a href="Sider/side2.html"><nobr>Om meg</nobr></a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <p><a href="/Sider/side3.html">Fotografi</a></p>
        </div>
        <div id="div3">
            <p><a href="/Sider/side4.html">Spillinteresse</a></p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="Informasjon">
        <div>
            <p id="Informasjon">
              asufauiw0faijsdjawidja0ij
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <footer>Copyright © 2022</footer>
    
</body>
</html>
```

So I have an assignment for my HTML/CSS class to make a website myself and one thing I still don't understand is how to position things when in flexbox. I am encountering these issues very occasionally and I could need some help.

The thing I am trying to achieve is to have my three pictures centered on the screen with space inbetween them and text underneath thats going to link to another page on the website.

I have tried to use position: relative; and just move it by pixels, but this only works on my own device, but when on a bigger screen it simply dosent work anymore. Anyone willing to help?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```css
body {
  margin: 5% 10%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.first {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/16/13/53/early-morning-7525151_960_720.jpg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.second {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/08/26/04/19/beach-7411683_960_720.jpg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.third {
  background: url(https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/09/11/14/43/whale-7446905_960_720.jpg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="first"></div>
    <a href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/10/16/13/53/early-morning-7525151_960_720.jpg">click me</a
      >
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="second"></div>
      <a
        href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/08/26/04/19/beach-7411683_960_720.jpg"
        >click me</a
      >
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="third"></div>
      <a
        href="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2022/09/11/14/43/whale-7446905_960_720.jpg"
        >click me</a
      >
    </div>
  </body>
```